# Smart Map cluster marker

Tags: plugin-smartmap

I use Smart Map for a project, but I have a question for this plugin.

Is it possible group the markers per cluster or I need see other options.

Tks

Answer (score 5):

**Yes, it's definitely possible to cluster your markers with Smart Map.**

In fact, anything that you can do with the Google Maps API can also be done with Smart Map:

> [Manipulating the map in JavaScript](https://plugins.doublesecretagency.com/smart-map/manipulating-the-map-in-javascript/)

I'd recommend adding the **[Marker Clusterer](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer)** JS library to your project.